# CentOS 6 - php5-pam-auth?

Tags: php, centos, pam, centos6

Where do I get an updated version of the PHP `pam_auth` module? Can't find it on `yum` and the latest version I can find to download is for PHP 4.3.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the answer to this myself, and eventually wound up having to solve it myself.  Since I'd found this question earlier in my searches, I figured I'd provide what worked for me :)

1. Download the pam_auth source from http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/pam/trunk/
   (or for convenience I have zipped the latest files, current as of revision 324283, [here](http://the-doktor.net/files/pam_auth.tar.gz))
2. Change into the directory you've downloaded/unzipped/etc the files into, and run the following commands:

   - phpize
   - ./configure
   - make
   - make install
3. Add **extension=pam.so** to your php.ini
4. Restart Apache; use phpinfo() to ensure the PAM module is running.

When verifying via phpinfo(), there should be a section like so:

[image: pam]

I successfully installed pam_auth on CentOS 5.6/Apache 2.2.3/PHP 5.3.10 using the above instructions; hopefully it will work just as well on CentOS 6. Good luck!

Comment: Doktor's process worked well, thanks for the help. On a minimal base install, I also needed to run: yum install gcc yum install pam-devel yum install make

Comment: Thank you, works on Debian too! (Just had to move the extension to my extension dir) after `make install`.